# creating classes without declaration

Tags: javascript, react-native, eval

It is possible to creating classes without direct definition?(Are eval function useful?)
I tried to do this But get errors such as Classes names not defined and nothing was returned from render and other errors

```java
import * as React from 'react';
import * as RN from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App(){
  let state = {
    screenNames: ['One','Two','Three'],
    screenJSXs: [],
  };
  let SCREENS = [],ClassString = '',Classes = [];
  state.screenNames.map((n)=>{
    state.screenJSXs.push(<RN.View> <RN.Text> Hi {n} </RN.Text> </RN.View>);
  });
  state.screenNames.map((n,i)=>{
    Classes.push('class ' + n + ' extends React.Component{render(){return (' + state.screenJSXs[i] + ')}}');
  // Example
  /*
    class One extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return (
          <View> <Text> Hi One </Text> </View>
        );
      }
    }
  */
  ClassString = Classes.join('\n');
  eval('ClassString');
  });
  state.screenNames.map((n,i)=>{
    SCREENS.push(<BottomTabs.Screen name={n} component={eval('n')} />);
  });
//if n pushed in eval function with '' then project work correctly but with blank pages else return Error : class name was not defined.
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomTabs.Navigator>
        {SCREENS}
      </BottomTabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

by this problems, how do I do?
Thank.

Comment: Don't use eval(). Explain what you are trying to do and we can help you find a better way.

Comment: Side note: a class isn't an expression.

Comment: i want to create a class with objects, not own decleration\
how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean "create a class with objects"? What does "not own declaration" mean? What is the reason you can just declare a class directly in your code? Please provide some more detail.

Comment: dear friend, I want to create multiple pages with classes, So I want to eval classes array\
but   I don't now how do I do.

Comment: Don't use eval(). Just write the code for the class directly and create your array from there.

Comment: [@Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) excuse me, can you give me a example?

Comment: Please [edit] your post with more details about what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` is never the right solution to any problem. Insead use React the way it is intended. Start with a component class:

```
class Screen extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <RN.View>
                <RN.Text>
                    Welcome back {this.props.name}
                </RN.Text>
            </RN.View>
        );
    }
}
```

Then create intances of this component and pass values to it as props:

```
let screens = screenNames.map(name => <Screen name=name />);
```

I use `map()` here instead of a for loop to more easily create a new array from the existing array of names.

You should only create an array like this if you are rendering a list of intances of a component. I think you don't really need this array because this is a single page, not a component within a page. You don't really have multiple pages here. You have **one** page with dynamic data. You don't need an array of classes. You need a single component class that can be used to render the data you pass it.

I suggest you review a React tutorial to increase your understanding about how components work.

Comment: dear friend, I want to create multiple pages with different JSX that I pushed own JSX to that class. what is your opinion?

Comment: @Naa8757 I suggest that you ask a new question. Show two or three examples of these "multiple pages" and how the JSX differs. The only difference in your example here is data that you can handle easily with a single class and passing props as I show in my answer here. If you have many pages that differ much more significantly, you will most likely have to just write the classes for each page. From there, you can start looking for patterns that you can encapsulate into reusable classes.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` parses plain javascript. What you are trying to do is parse jsx. jsx isn't plain javascript. It's a syntax sugar transpiled by transpilator when the project is built - before it's send to the client.
You can try use React withotu jsx https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
But What you should really do is never use eval.